# FMLA 12-week limit (US)

Tags: united-states, benefits, leave-of-absence

I'm about to take a 16-week period of unpaid leave. My employer will maintain my medical cover for the first 12 weeks of that, as required by [FMLA](https://www.dol.gov/general/topic/workhours/fmla). However, they are actually willing to maintain cover for the final 4 weeks as well. I live and work in Texas and, in case it matters, I am considered to be an "exempt" employee.

But, someone in HR is saying that the 12-week limit in the law is not only an "up to" maximum, it is also a "no more than" maximum. In other words, she is saying that while the FMLA rules **require** the employer to maintain the employee's medical cover for (up to) 12 weeks, the same rules also explicitly **prohibit** the employer from maintaining the employee's health benefits for any more than 12 weeks.

If it turns out that is the case then I can still fall back on COBRA to maintain my cover for weeks 13 through 16, but I haven't been able to find anything definitive on a actual prohibition above 12 weeks.

Does anyone know how it works (and, ideally, *how* you know)?

Comment: Thanks Joe. Do you have a source for that? It's my gut feel too (why would the law forbid an employer being *more* generous than required?), but I'm trying to get something official-ish I can point the HR lady to.

Comment: Which US state are you in?

Comment: I am in the state of Texas

Answer (score 5):

The employer can exceed the FMLA benefits.

The law says you can't lose your job if you take the leave. Your employer can decide to pay you even if your are out of sick and vacation.

The law says you have to be provided the same health insurance. Your employer can decide to cover your portion of the premium.

The law defines who is covered. The employer can decide that everybody is covered.

What happens when the required leave runs out, depends on your employer. They can decide you can be gone longer. They can decide to pay you longer.

The issue is their insurance contract. The group policy has rules. The insurance company offers different options such as starting on day one, starting on the first day of the second month. Each options comes with a different cost and set of rules.

The question is can they still cover you as a member of the group if you aren't performing a minimum amount of work? That is a question for the person who coordinates the FMLA coverage. You need to get it in writing so there are no surprises at the end. My company uses a 3rd party to coordinate the FMLA coverage, they might be the ones who have all the information.

The scheduling of the return to work is always important. Some places have strict rules, others are more relaxed. Some even allow longer leave if the last few weeks are done part-time.

Comment: Thank you. I suspect that may be true, and that my HR person has been given the correct conclusion -- they cannot cover over 12 weeks -- but for the wrong reason -- "it's the law", instead of "it's the insurer".